# How do I make ftdetect rule recognize syntax statement at the end of a file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm using [a syntax highlight plugin](https://github.com/chr4/nginx.vim) for Nginx files. Its `ftdetect` looks like this:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.nginx set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile nginx*.conf set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile *nginx.conf set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile */etc/nginx/* set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile */usr/local/nginx/conf/* set ft=nginx
au BufRead,BufNewFile */nginx/*.conf set ft=nginx
```

It works well with local configuration files, but when I open a file which is outside the list of predefined directories, there is no syntax highlighting, even when the file ends by the following line:

```
# vim: syntax=nginx ts=4 sw=4 sts=4
```

If, inside vim, I run `:setf nginx`, then the syntax is back.

How do I change `ftdetect` to be able to benefit from syntax highlighting automatically based on the presence of `# vim: syntax=nginx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct modeline syntax sets options, so

```
# vim: filetype=nginx ts=4 sw=4 sts=4
```

Or the short version `ft`

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists with `filetype`, as well as with `ft` (i.e. the syntax highlighting is off, and I have to type `:setf nginx` to get it.

Comment: Are the tabstop settings being applied? It’s bizarre to me that `setf` works, since it shouldn’t change anything if a filetype has already been set. This would imply those files have no filetype.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko sorry meant to ping you there^

Comment: Indeed, tabstop settings are ignored as well, the default settings being used. I tried to copy apache2.conf file to a different location and using a different name: same problem here, despite "# vim:..." at the end, it's not detected as Apache configuration file. Any idea what could cause this behavior? Or do you want me to accept your answer and open a separate question?

Comment: No, if it’s not working than we haven’t resolved your problem. Can you confirm that modelines work in other files?

Comment: Found it. You pointed me to the right direction by giving the official name of that thing at the last line. I searched for `modeline`; it appears that it wasn't enabled (and now that I enabled it in .vimrc, it works. Not sure if it was disabled by one of the plugins or not enabled by default, but at least it works now. Thank you.